# Find all elements on a page whose element ID contains a certain text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, search, filter, find, wildcard

I'm trying to find all elements on a page whose element ID contains a certain text. I'll then need to filter the found elements based on whether they are hidden or not. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery selector regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 242, accepted):

```
$('*[id*=mytext]:visible').each(function() {
    $(this).doStuff();
});
```

Note the asterisk '*' at the beginning of the selector [matches all elements](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/all).

See the [Attribute Contains Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), as well as the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selectors.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that when matching against an element's `id` you do not use quotes, where when matching against a `name` you do.  `$('*[name*="myname"]:visible')`  Not the most intuitive and has caught me up before.

Comment: I replaced  $(this).doStuff(); with  this.doStuff(); and worked

Answer (score 178):

If you're finding by **Contains** then it'll be like this

```
    $("input[id*='DiscountType']").each(function (i, el) {
         //It'll be an array of elements
     });
```

If you're finding by **Starts With** then it'll be like this

```
    $("input[id^='DiscountType']").each(function (i, el) {
         //It'll be an array of elements
     });
```

If you're finding by **Ends With** then it'll be like this

```
     $("input[id$='DiscountType']").each(function (i, el) {
         //It'll be an array of elements
     });
```

If you want to select elements which **id is not a given string**

```
    $("input[id!='DiscountType']").each(function (i, el) {
         //It'll be an array of elements
     });
```

If you want to select elements which **name contains a given word, delimited by spaces**

```
     $("input[name~='DiscountType']").each(function (i, el) {
         //It'll be an array of elements
     });
```

If you want to select elements which **id is equal to a given string or starting with that string followed by a hyphen**

```
     $("input[id|='DiscountType']").each(function (i, el) {
         //It'll be an array of elements
     });
```

Comment: Hello, how can I use a selector to select those elements whose id belongs to an array.

Answer (score 24):

This selects all DIVs with an ID containing 'foo' and that are visible

```
$("div:visible[id*='foo']");
```

Comment: If im searching for textbox elements rather than divs, is it simply $("input:visible[id*='foo']"); ?

Comment: it would be $("input[type='textbox'][id*='foo']:visible")

Comment: @port-zero - the single quotes around 'foo' are not necessary

Comment: if you are trying to get the value of the elements ( in my case spans ) you have to get `$(this)[0].innerText`

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to both of you. This worked perfectly for me.

```
$("input[type='text'][id*=" + strID + "]:visible").each(function() {
    this.value=strVal;
});
```