# Combine jQuery expand all toggle functions

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've got an FAQ page that has about 15 sections. Each question uses slideToggle to expand each answer. That's all fine. The trouble is each section needs an "expand/collapse all", which will expand all questions only within that specific section. The script I'm using works perfect, it's just that I have to create a block of the same script for each section .. example:

```
$('#faq-content a.all').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('collapse')) {
        $('#faq-content dt.opened').click();
    } else $('#faq-content dt:not(.opened)').click();
    $(this).toggleClass('expand collapse');
    return false;
});

$('#faq-hardware a.all').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('collapse')) {
        $('#faq-hardware dt.opened').click();
    } else $('#faq-hardware dt:not(.opened)').click();
    $(this).toggleClass('expand collapse');
    return false;
});
```

I was wondering if it's possible to have a unified way to control all sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your structure of the dom, you should be able to do this with just some classes and remove the dependency for the `Id`

```
$('.faq a.all').click(function() {
    var $faq = $(this).parent(); //Where a is a child of .faq
    if ($(this).hasClass('collapse')) {
        $faq.find('dt.opened').click();
    } else{
      $faq.find('dt:not(.opened)').click();
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('expand collapse');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trying using an the wildcard asterik *

`$('#faq*).click(function() { ..`

see: [Find all elements on a page whose element ID contains a certain text using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206739/jquery-wildcard-search)

Also you can give assign a class to each of the element you want to toggle and then using the class selector to expand/collapse.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like

```
$("[id^=faq-]").click(function() { ..
```

That would allow you select any id's that *begin with* "faq-".

Good luck!