# select some element by ID in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find all elements on a page whose element ID contains a certain text using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206739/find-all-elements-on-a-page-whose-element-id-contains-a-certain-text-using-jquery)

I need to select all elements have "user" word in their ID.

in attribute I will do it by $= but how can I do it by element ID?

Comment: You need the wildcard selector search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206739/jquery-wildcard-search

Comment: The jQuery documentation is quite good: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3):

You'd do it with the use of the [`*=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector:

```
$('[id*="user"]').doStuff();
```

Comment: The id attribute can't have spaces.  The `~=` attribute selects words that are delimited by spaces.  You'd need to use `*=`.

Comment: also, the `*` at the front of the attribute selector is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this

`$('[id*="user"]')`

selects all elements

`[id` with an `id`

`*="user"` that contains user

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/QXGen/2/

Here is more info on the attribute contains selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: the leading `*` is redundant. All CSS selectors are parsed from right-to-left, meaning the attribute selector is interpreted first, so that `*` will just slow the selector down after it gets all the elements it needs.

Comment: Thanks @Chris.  Noted and edited above.

Answer (score 2):

An attribute selector like `$('[id*="user"]')` will match elements with the id 'user', 'users', 'superuser', 'abusers', 'user-details', etc.

If you had a more rigid structure for your IDs and wanted to only match things like 'user' and 'super-user' etc., you could try something like:

```
var userWordTest = RegExp("\\b" + "user" + "\\b");
$('[id]').filter(function() { return userWordTest.test(this.id); })
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) variant of the named attribute selector with the id attribute.

```
$('[id*="user"]')...
```