# Search element inside element jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

In my HTML page DOM what I want to achieve is there is `<li>` tag with id `'liPref'` and I want to search if that 'lipref' element has some element whose id contains string `'dlpref'` as its inner HTML.

I am not getting any idea how do I achieve that using jQuery selectors.

Comment: As a start: [Find all elements on a page whose element ID contains a certain text using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1206739/218196)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#liPref").find("[id*='dlpref']").each(function(){
//do something here
});
```

For getting length:

```
 $("#liPref").find("[id*='dlpref']").length;
```

**[attribute-contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**

Comment: Please link to the documentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check whether the liPref element has a an element with id containing the given string

```
if($('#liPref').has('[id*=dlpref]').length){
   alert('foune')
}
```

[.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/), [attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: @FelixKling no.. it is a filter... `is` returns s boolean... `Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.` - the is() implementation can be `$('#liPref').is(':has([id*=dlpref])')`

Comment: Uh sorry. That's one of those ambiguous method names :)

Comment: @FelixKling yes... the name looks like it returns a boolean value... I had the same doubt

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use attribute [**contains *=**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector:

```
if($("#liPref [id*='dlpref']").length) { 
   // Existed
}
```