# Get the ID of an element where the class contains a given string

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to figure out a way to get the ID of an element, depending on whether its class contains something.  I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it than I currently am, but having looked around nothing fits exactly the need I have.  The code I currently have is, where I am looking for a div element whose class contains the string "one" but is not limited to that.  Currently there is only one element containing this string but the alert provides me with [Object NodeList] (I may well be overcomplicating this):

```
$idToMove = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="one"]');
        alert($idToMove);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all elements on a page whose element ID contains a certain text using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206739/find-all-elements-on-a-page-whose-element-id-contains-a-certain-text-using-jquer)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) Returns a node list (kind of like an array), if you are sure there will only ever be one you have a couple options.

1) Use `.querySelector` instead:

```
// returns the first node that matches
var elm = document.querySelector('div[class~="one"]');
console.log(elm.id);
```

2) Access the first element in the returned list:

```
// returns all nodes that match
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('div[class~="one"]');
console.log(elms[0].id);
```

Make sure to null check returns of `.querySelector` and length check returns of `.querySelectorAll`.

Notice also, that I use `~=` and not `^=`. You can read [on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) about the difference between all the equality operators. But for these two:

> [attr~=value]
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "value".
>
> [attr^=value]
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose first value is prefixed by "value".

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I seem to be returning null (I've used part resolution 1 to solve this).  Could it be that I am setting the class to include "one" with php?  It **is** successfully making the class contain the string "one" but when I attempt to console.log it errors that it can't give me the id of null.

Comment: Updated answer, you need `~=` and not `^=`.

Answer (score 2):

I think with "*" it works in more cases

```js
document.querySelector('div[class*="words"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

i tried it works absolutely amazing

```
window.frames[0].document.querySelector('td[id*="sss"]')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

First get element from DOM and than from that element get id attribute:

1- If you need only first element then use querySelector like this:

```
let elms = document.querySelector('div[class~="one"]')[0].id
console.log(elms)
```

2- If you need all element those have this class then use querySelectorAll like this:

```
let elms = document.querySelectorAll('div[class~="one"]')

for(let i=0; i<elms.length; i++)
{
console.log(elms[i].id)
}
```