# find where id string contains a certain string

Tags: javascript

Im trying to find items that have a value set to true, but Im having a difficult time to find ids containing a certain string

`id*['_conf']`

```
var items = $jointlist.find("input[type=hidden] id*['_conf']").filter(function() { return this.value == 'true'});
```

Please can you help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all elements on a page whose element ID contains a certain text using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206739/find-all-elements-on-a-page-whose-element-id-contains-a-certain-text-using-jquer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close, your `id` selector is a bit off:

```
$jointlist.find("input[type=hidden] [id*='_conf']")
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: well that was embarrassing. Thanks