# Find all DOM elements which ID contains a string using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

Find all DOM elements which ID contains a string, but I want to use vanillaJS. I know that in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206739/find-all-elements-on-a-page-whose-element-id-contains-a-certain-text-using-jquer) there is a solution using jQuery, but in this case, I want to use only pure javascript.

I know that with this  :

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id='parteOfanID']")
```

We can get all elements which as the attribute id with the value "parteOfanID".

Thank you

Comment: you mean which contain same id name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `*=` with the attribut selector `[]` like :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id*="string_here"]')
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[id*="identifier_"]').length);
```

```html
<span id="test"></span>
<span id="identifier_1"></span>
<span id="identifier_2"></span>
<span id="identifier_3"></span>
<span id="test"></span>
<span id="identifier_4"></span>
<span id="test"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` that gets a CSS selector (like jQuery) and returns `NodeList`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="some text"]');
```