# JQuery, how to find list of div's with similar ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a structure of html like this:

```
<div id="triger1">some elements inside</div>
<div id="triger2">some elements inside</div>
<div id="triger3">some elements inside</div>
<div id="triger4">some elements inside</div>
```

How do I get array of all the div's in JQuery with the triger ID in them (as you can see, they all have triger but different numbering eg. triger1, triger2 etc...)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$("div[id^='triger']")
```

This will return all `<div>` with `id` starting (`^=`) with `triger`.

You can get more information about the various jQuery selectors in the jQuery docs:

> [API/Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

Comment: Can we use it for multiple ids with the (^=). For ex.: to get the divs that starts with either 'trigger' or 'smart'?

Comment: **@Prasad:** Sure! Simply use `$("div[id^='trigger'],div[id^='smart']")`

Comment: @AndrewMoore will this always return an ordered array?  Or might this randomly sort my divs into the array?

Comment: @Alan_s: It always returns the results in DOM order. (Except for a `.parents()` query; where the order is reversed since you are walking up the tree)

Answer (score 7):

you can actually use a regular expression in a selector to achieve exactly what you are looking for, as such:

```
$("div:regex(id, yourRegularExpression)");
```

(Note: this does require the [regex-selector](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) plugin)

Someone asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions).

You can read all about regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

As others have pointed out, you can achieve the same result like this:

```
$("div[id^='partOfID']");
```

by using a simple jQuery selector. For more complex selections, though, you will need to use the [regex plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) or do it manually, as noted in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions).

good luck!

Comment: That requires a custom filter.

Comment: yeup! already updated the answer with the link to it and an alternative way for simpler queries

Answer (score 7):

Select all `div` elements whose `id` attribute contains the string `triger`:

```
$('div[id*="triger"]');
```

There's more about using `*=` in the jQuery documentation: [Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var trigerList = $("div[id^='triger']");
```