# Find total element within a div with certain id

Tags: jquery, find, element

I have the following script:

```
<div>
  <p id="example1"></p>
  <div></div>
  <p id="example2"></p>
  <div></div>
  <p id="example3"></p>
  <p id="example4"></p>
  <p id="example5"></p>
</div>
```

Is it possible to write a jquery function to determine the total number of element id with matching this keyword "example" when the page is loaded?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery selector regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225611/jquery-how-to-find-list-of-divs-with-similar-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check-it Out:**

```
alert($("div p[id^='example']").length);
```

**[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/usezo4/4)**

OR

refer this link [**JQuery Selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

where u can use selectors as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

Sukhi answered you correctly.

Code fragment: `p[id^='emample']` implies any p "starts with" the "example" word in id attribute.

But what if you want to check "ends with" condition? Simply replace ^ with $, so your code will be somthing like this: `p[id$='1']` to select any id which has "1" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute contains selector functionality:

```
$('p[id*="example"]').length;
```