# jQuery find img

Tags: jquery, image

```
<img src="http://site.com/some/category/thread_17.jpg" />
<img src="http://site.com/other/thread_17.jpg" />
```

How to find the last image on the page, that have "`thread_`" after last "`/`" in its `src` attribute?

Script should throw `src` to some `var`iable.

Ajax is used to find the images on external page

```
$.ajaxQueue({
 url: link, 
 type: 'GET',
 success: function(data) {
  var src = $('.slide img', data).attr('src');
 }
});
```

It gives attribute of the last image from `.slide` block.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.slide img[src*=\\/thread_]:last', data)` might do it

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through ALL of the images you have & perform regex on them, like this:

```
$('.slide img', data).each(function(index){
   src = $(this).attr('src');
   stringarray = src.split('/');
   last_piece = stringarray[stringarray.length-1]
   regexpatt = /thread_/
   if ( regexpatt.test(last_piece) )
   {
      alert('we have a winner!');
   }
   else
   {
      alert('that was disappointing');
   }
});
```

I am sure there is probably a more elegant way - you should probably search through the jquery docs for it, but this works... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var src = $(data).find('.slide img').last().attr('src');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex in selectors

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

[jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Hope this can help

Regargs.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
var srcAttr = $('.slide img[src*=\/]', data).filter(function() {

            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            return src.substr(src.lastIndexOf("/")).indexOf('thread_') >= 0

        }).last().attr('src');
```

Here I am doing the following things.

1. The selector gets us all the images
   with their src tags having a "/".
2. Filtering the images that have
   "thread_" after the last "/"
3. Taking the last image of all such
   images
4. Taking the src attribute of it.

Comment: I tested this and found that it is working with the examples you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess, use a little [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) with a RegExp, and then the [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last) element in the set, grab its src using [`.attr('src')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
var src = $('.slide img', data).filter(function() {
  // only keep <img> whos src have '/thread_' without another '/' before the end
  return $(this).attr('src').match(/\/thread_[^\/]*$/);
}).last().attr('src');
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/dug5L/)