# How to get elements from HTML document using JavaScript by specific tags reg expression?

Tags: javascript

I want to get all elements from `document` which starts with ge-. Example `<ge-survey></ge-survey> <ge-sombody></ge-sombody> <ge-...></ge-...>`.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*"); // <<-- now return all
```

also I tried :

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("^=ge-");
```

but get :

```
geadele.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '^=ge-' is not a valid selector.
```

Also I tried:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("^=ge-"); // return epty HTMLcollection
```

my html:

```
...
</head>
<body>
  <ge-survey></ge-survey>
  <ge-element></ge-element>
</body>
...
```

Comment: no I want get array of elements from HTML document by tags <ge-xxx> using reg expresions. It is question about JavaScript reg expressions more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getElementByName & Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184093/getelementbyname-regex)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know all `ge-`elements, which you want to get, you can use `document.getElementsByTagName('ge-somebody')` and concatenate result.

```
var ge1Elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('ge-1'));
var ge2Elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('ge-2'));
...
var geElements = [].concat(ge1Elements, ge2Elements, ge3Elements);
```

In my opinion this approach in documents with a large number of elements is faster than regexp, but I didn't any benchmarks.

If you don't know all posible `ge-` elements, you can get it by filtering all elements:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var geElements = [];
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if(elements[i].tagName.indexOf('GE-') === 0){
      geElements.push(elements[i]);
    }
}
console.log(geElements);
```

Comment: I tried it but I thing is better use prepared JavaScript decision with reg expressions, not need write more code;

Comment: I dont know about ge elements in html.

Comment: @EdgarasKarka If you don't know a set of all ge-tags, you should use the second approach with filtering any collection of html-elements by tagName matching

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector` and use a 'starts with' type css selector:
[Can I use a regular expression in querySelectorAll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791527/can-i-use-a-regular-expression-in-queryselectorall)

Comment: I tried document.querySelectorAll("^=ge-"); but get error. Look to post