# Is it possible to getElementsByClassName with partial name on Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I need to get all innerText of all elements that partially match a given string.

Heres a snippet of the code:

```
<span class="18794221455sarasa">Some text</span>
```

The class always ends with 'sarasa' the numbers are dynamic.
I want to run it on a chrome extension that's why I need it to be on plain Javascript

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix

Comment: Get all elements that have a `class`, then check whether the class matches the pattern in your loop body.

Comment: @Amy The question is about a suffix, not prefix.

Comment: @Barmar The top answer also has "contains the substring".  Read past the title.

Comment: ^ for starting with $ for ending with

Comment: This one should do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3184523/1423259

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getElementByName & Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184093/getelementbyname-regex)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you can't use `getElementsByClassName` like that.

But you can use `querySelectorAll` with a CSS attribute selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class$="sarasa"]')
```

will give you a collection of the DOM elements you want.

See an explanation of this selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class$=sarasa]")
```