# jQuery Selector Question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following jQuery code which all works fine:

```
         $("#sidebar .m3, #sidebar .m5").toggle(function() {                  
               $(this).find("img").attr({­src:"images/Up.png"});                 
               }, function() {
               $(this).find("img").attr({­src:"images/Down.png"});                  
         });
```

My question is, instead of individually specifying $("#sidebar .m3, #sidebar .m5"), where my menu items may have the classes m1,m2,m3,m4,m5 etc,
is there anyway of having something like:

```
$("#sidebar .m[*]").
```

That will cater for any number after the ".m" , so I don't need to hard code m3 or m5?

Thanks.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Comment: for future reference why not just give the common things a common classname?

Comment: Good point Brandon - will go back and change this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's the only (or first) class applied to the menu item you can use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
$('#sidebar [class^=m]')...
```

A better way would be to give them all a common class, like `menu-item`, in addition to your other class that functions simply as a selector to group them all, then simply use:

```
$('#sidebar .menu-item')...
```

Comment: +1 tho just to clarify the menu item would end up looking something like `<li class="m1 menu-item">...</li>`

Comment: @Nick -- that's the first sentence in the answer.

Comment: Hahaha, had my screen scrolled where that line was just out of view, removing that ignorant comment :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this:

```
$(".m3, .m5", "#sidebar")
```

But...you're not restricted to one class, can you just use multiple?  To use multiple classes just have a space between them, for example:

```
<div class="m5 myClass">Stuff</div>
<div class="m3 myClass">Stuff 2</div>
```

Then you can use *that* class, like this:

```
$("#sidebar .myClass")
```

---

Or, say your structure is like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="m5">Stuff</div>
  <div class="m3">Stuff 2</div>
</div>
```

You can just use the [child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), like this:

```
$("#sidebar > div")
```

---

There are of course *other* ways to skin this cat as well, it just depends on what your markup is.

Answer (score 2):

Can you tackle it a slightly different way???

If you have the ability to manipulate your HTML could add an additional class to all the menu items as a placeholder (for example, call the class 'm').

This would allow you to search on:
     $("#sidebar .m)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the begins-with selector:

```
$("#sidebar *[class^='m']")
```