# jQuery - Get a element class based on a prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the fastest way possible to get a string like "fade" from the classes in the element below?

```
<div class="MyElement fx-fade"> ... </div>
```

Comment: What would this help you do? I'm unsure what you mean.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var classes = $('.MyElement').attr('class').split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
  var matches = /^fx\-(.+)/.exec(classes[i]);
  if (matches != null) {
    var fxclass = matches[1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 75):

If you wanted to look for something that ended in 'fade' you would use:

```
$("*[class$='fade']")
```

And for elements with a class that started with 'fade' you would use:

```
$("*[class^='fade']")
```

And to get elements that contain 'fade' you would use (this would be quicker than going through the class names string)

```
$("*[class*='fade']")
```

The `*` gets all elements so you could replace this with the element you wanted.

If you want elements that has a classname that starts with `fx-` you would do:

```
var classname = "";
var elArray = $("*[class*='fx-']");
    
for (var a = 0; a < elArray.length; a++) {
   // fade
    classname = elArray[a].split("-")[1]; 
}
```

The array used in the for loop would have all the elements with the classnames like 'fx-'.

Rather than than the for loop checking the elements for the correct class name.

More information at [jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: elArray[a].split is not a function?

Comment: this is not working for me ...

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$("div[class*='fade']")
```

[More info](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 3):

The question title and the question do not exactly match (title asks for prefix, question asks for suffix/partial)

---

## 1. Select elements by class-prefix

Combine following two jQuery/CSS selectors:

```
$( "[class^='fx-'],[class*=' fx-']" )
```

- `[class^='fx-']` [Starts-With-Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
  Find elements where the first letters of the entire class attribute starts with "fx-"
  e.g. `<a class="fx-fade MyElement anything">`
- `[class*=' fx-']` [Contains-Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
  Find elements where a *space + "fx-"* is found anywhere inside the class attribute
  e.g. `<a class="MyElement fx-fade anything">`

This selector makes sure, that you do not get false positives such as `<a class="MyElement sfx-none">`

---

## 2. Select elements by class-suffix

Almost identical to the prefix selector:

```
$( "[class$='-fade'],[class*='-fade ']" )
```

- `[class$='-fade']` [End-With-Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)
  Find elements where the last letters of the entire class attribute are with "-fade"
  e.g. `<a class="MyElement anything fx-fade">`
- `[class*='-fade ']` [Contains-Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
  Find elements where a *"-fade" + space* is found anywhere inside the class attribute
  e.g. `<a class="anything fx-fade MyElement">`

This selector makes sure, that you do not get false positives such as `<a class="MyElement sfx-none">`

---

## 3. Select elements by class-substring

When you need to find a substring that is neither the start nor the end of a class name, use the selector suggested in the other answers:

```
$( "[class*='fade']" )
```

- `[class*='fade']` [Contains-Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
  Find elements where *"fade"* is found anywhere inside the class attribute
  e.g. `<a class="fx-fade-out">`

Warning: This also finds `"no-fade"` or `"faded"`. Use the Contains-Selector with care!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [JQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions). It might be exactly what you need! :)

Comment: I think you did the same thing I did.  I misread the question, answered it, and then deleted my answer.  The OP isn't asking how to filter elements given the partial match.  I think given the element, the OP is asking how to extract part of the attribute.

Comment: Ah! In that case, I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with something like:

```
//Split class list into individual classes:
var classes = $(".MyElement").attr("class").split(" ");
var fxType;

//Loop through them:
for (var i = 0, max = classes.elngth; i < max; i++) {
  var class = classes[i].split("-");
  //Check if the current one is prefixed with 'fx':
  if (class[0] == "fx") {
    //It is an FX - do whatever you want with it, the type of FX is stored in class[1], ie:
    fxType = class[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Careful, `class` is a reserved word in javascript and will cause an error in some browsers.

Comment: Oops, had a feeling it might be. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This simple snippet we use in our sites:

```js
/**
 * Script to load a popup container for share buttons
 *
 * Possible usage for Facebook, Twitter and Google:
 *
 * <a class="share-buttons-fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php the_title(); ?>">Facebook</a>
 * <a class="share-buttons-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php the_title(); ?>: <?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">Twitter</a>
 * <a class="share-buttons-google" href="http://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">Google+</a>
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Whenever an anchor with the class with share-button in it is clicked
    $("a[class*='share-button']").click(function () {
        // Variables to set the size of the popup container
        var windowWidth = 500;
        var windowHeight = 255;

        // Variables to set the position of the popup container
        var positionWindowLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
        var positionWindowTop = (screen.height / 3) - (windowHeight / 3);

        // Create new windows with the opening url of the href attribute of the anchor and the above variables
        var popupWindow = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=nolocation=no,menubar=no,resizable=noe,height=' + windowHeight + ',width=' + windowWidth + ',top=' + positionWindowTop + ', left=' + positionWindowLeft);

        // If the default windows is focused
        if (window.focus) {
            // Change the focus to the the popup window
            popupWindow.focus();
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```