# How to get all the class name of an element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some li's

```
 li class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even"  
 li class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd"  
 li class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even"  
 li class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd"
```

Now on `hover` i am adding a class **selected** to corresponding li. Suppose i `hover` on first li element, selected classes get added to this li. So i will have
li class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even **selected**". Now how do i get the **views-row-2** class of this selected li.Similarly if second li is selected i need **views-row-3** class and so on. Please help

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery/1227309#1227309). Should answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several options, but this is a good one:

```
views_row = $("li.selected").attr("class").match(/(views\-row\-[0-9]+)/)[0];
```

Comment: Glad to finally contribute on SO a bit :) I should note that that will yield an error if there are no matches, so you should make sure to do a check that the array has a result before accessing it.

Comment: @dtbarne : hi dtbarne .. can you tell me why is [0] used in the end

Comment: String.match() returns an array, so that grabs the first match from the array.

Answer (score 1):

<del>You haven't mentioned what's special about the `view-rows-2` class:</del>

- <del>Do you already know which class you want?</del>
- <del>Will it always be this class?</del>

<del>With what information you've given, here are my suggestions:</del>

1. <del>You might want to check out [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)</del>
2. <del>If you want all classes for an element, see [Get class list for element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery/1227309#1227309)</del>

So if you want to get classes based on a prefix (which in your case seems to be `views-row-`, you could use what's suggested in the answers to these SO question: [jQuery - Get a element class based on a prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204632/jquery-get-a-element-class-based-on-a-prefix) and [jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Comment: in hasClass he has to pass whole class name i.e. views-row views-row-2 views-row-even selected not views-row-2.

Comment: My objective is, suppose first li is selected i need views-row-2 class , similarly if 2nd li is selected i need views-row-3 class and so on

Comment: @JAB Ah, ok, so it seems like you want what I've suggested in #3 in my edited answer

Comment: @Vivek, I don't understand. For `hasClass()`, he would use it something like `$('selector').hasClass('views-row-2')` which would return `true` or `false` based on whether the element had the class or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can use indeOf() something like this...suppose you have that selected class as you have written..

```
if(class.indexOf('views-row-2')!=-1){
    //do what ever you want to do, you can use sbstr() to get your class name too.
 }
```