# selecting classes using wildcard not exact class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several classes that I want to select .group1-1 .group1-2 .group1-3, each one of these has 50 elements under it.

Is there a way to select all classes that start with group1 (so I end up selecting group1-1, group1-2, group1-3), something like `$(".group1"+*)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use something along the lines of this if you'd like to avoid regex:

```
$("[class^='group1-']").click(function () {
    var groupNumber = $(this).attr('class').split('-')[1];
    alert('Yep, you clicked group1-' + groupNumber); 
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/iwasrobbed/7bjtb/

Comment: Take care as this solution will not match for elements that have multiple classes, if the 'group1-*' class is not the first listed in the 'class' attribute. See http://jsfiddle.net/vQk9U/2/ for an example of this.

Comment: ... in addition, switching from '^=' to '\*=' will work, until you run into issues where 'group1-' matches as a substring of another class name, such as 'mygroup1-*' :-)

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions) discusses jquery wildcard / regex selectors.  Which basically allow you to use a regular expression to specify matching classes.