# Wildcards in jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, sizzle

I'm trying to use a wildcard to get the id of all the elements whose id begin with "jander". I tried `$('#jander*')`, `$('#jander%')` but it doesn't work..

I know I can use classes of the elements to solve it, but it is also possible using wildcards??

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var prueba = [];

  $('#jander').each(function () {
    prueba.push($(this).attr('id'));
  });

  alert(prueba);


});

</script>

<div id="jander1"></div>
<div id="jander2"></div>
```

Comment: This is a question about jQuery (or more exactly the Sizzle engine).

Comment: Just a note: It would be much faster to do it with classes as jQuery or Sizzle can make use of browser functions (should not make much of a difference for modern browsers though).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery selector regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Comment: Also, an important thing to note is that `$("[id*=jander]")` would select all elements with an ID containing the string jander.

Answer (score 1392, accepted):

To get all the elements starting with "jander" you should use:

```
$("[id^=jander]")
```

To get those that end with "jander"

```
$("[id$=jander]")
```

See also the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: The docs give this example: `$('input[name^="news"]').val('news here!')`

Answer (score 135):

Since the title suggests wildcard you could also use this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log($('[id*=ander]'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jander1"></div>
<div id="jander2"></div>
```

This will select the given string anywhere in the `id`.

Answer (score 42):

Try the jQuery starts-with

> selector, '^=', eg

```
[id^="jander"]
```

I have to ask though, why don't you want to do this using classes?

Comment: Thanks for the classes hint, that brought me to the right direction!

Answer (score 38):

for classes you can use:

```
div[class^="jander"]
```

Answer (score 16):

To **get the id** from the wildcard match:

```js
$('[id^=pick_]').click(
  function(event) {

    // Do something with the id # here: 
    alert('Picked: '+ event.target.id.slice(5));

  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pick_1">moo1</div>
<div id="pick_2">moo2</div>
<div id="pick_3">moo3</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

When you have a more complex id string the double quotes are mandatory.

For example if you have an id like this: `id="2.2"`, the correct way to access it is: `$('input[id="2.2"]')`

As much as possible use the double quotes, for safety reasons.