# find elements which have the some id pattern

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I generate markup dynamically and `id` for inputs elements:

```
<div class="wrap_input fancy_form" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 28px;">
        @foreach(var seatType in Model.UsingSeatType)
        {
            int i = 1;
            <p class="inp_label" style="width: 50px;">@(seatType.Value):</p>
            <i>&nbsp;</i>
            <input type="text" id="type@(i)" value="" data-price=""  style="width: 50px;" />
            i++;
        }
    </div>
```

How can I find all this inputs(type1, type2, type3 and so on)?

```
 $("#type?").spinner();
```

Thanks.

Comment: may be duplicate question check out this [link][1]




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this code

```
$('.wrap_input.fancy_form input[type=text][id^=type]').spinner();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about you make the following changes:

Add a class to your input:

```
<input class="seat_type" type="text" id="type@(i)" value="" data-price=""  style="width: 50px;" />
```

Use jQuery selector on the class

```
$(".seat_type").spinner();
```

I suggest these changes because it would be easier to read for most people.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('input[id^="type"]').spinner();
```

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).