# How to select jquery elements containing a certain character string?

Tags: jquery

Say I have the following:

```
<div id="hellokat"></div>
<div id="hellodog"></div>
<div id="byekat"></div>
<div id="byedog"></div>
```

I know I can select divs individually with $('#hellokat') and $('hellodog'), but I want to select all divs containing "hello" at the beginning of their ids at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wildcards in jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors)

Simply use regular expressions in selectors:

```
$("div[id^=hello]").hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use *[attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)*.

```
$('div[id^="hello"]')
```