# jquery id identifier

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wildcards in jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors)

Say I have several buttons on my page, with id tags as `id_1`, `id_2`, `id_3` etc

I want a function to cover all of them being pressed, so something that checks if the first 3 characters are `id_`.

```
 $("?????").click(function(event) {
```

What replaces the `??????`

I can't use classes instead, in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would also work:

```
$('[id^=id_]').click(function() {
  //Do stuff here
});
```

This selects all elements whose `id` attribute begins with `id_`, so `id_1`, `id_2`, `id_3`, etc... would all be selected.

However, it might be more appropriate to use the `class` attribute as a selector. Unlike the `id` attribute, the `class` attribute does not have to be unique. So, for example, you can have 5 buttons on your page, each with a class name of `clickMe`, and employ the following code which will listen for a click on any of the buttons:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function() {
  //Do stuff here
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a little question. The `[id` part means "with attribute id" and the rest means "starting with `id_`", right?

Comment: @Linuxios Yes, the `[id` portion is the name of the attribute, and `id_` is the beginning of the attribute value.

Comment: @Linuxios if you found my answer helpful, could you please hit the checkmark beside it?

Comment: Little misunderstanding here. I'm not the Op. ;)!

Comment: Ummm... yeah. Sorry, now I see that. ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about this (I'm pretty new to JavaScript, might not work):

```
for(var i = 0; i < maxId; i++) {
  $("#id_"+i).click(function(e) {
    //Blah blah blah
  });
}
```

Comment: @spryno724: Thanks! Sometimes I pull things out of my hat the work. Other times, not. Glad this was a time that works :).

Comment: you missed out the closing brace for the `click(function(e) { });`

Comment: The for loop is unnecessary, when you can use `^=` (see [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431))

Comment: @Linuxios Sorry my quick scan didn't notice that. lol

Comment: @nico: I know. But I know bery little about JS, so this is all I knew how to do. But my +1 goes to spryno for his elegant answer.

Comment: @Linuxios: well, now you know another trick ;)

Comment: @nico: Learn something new everyday on SO, eh?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $('button[id^="id_"]').on('click', function(e){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});​
```

[**Here's**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/6VRYv/) an example.