# Selecting element which starts with "abc" and ends with "xyz"

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have elements in my page with ids like "abc_1_2_3_xyz" .How do I select element in Jquery which starts with "abc" and ends with "xyz"?

```
$('div[id^="abc"], div[id$="xyz"]');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use 2 attribute selectors.

```
$('div[id^="abc"][id$="xyz"]');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
$('div[id^="abc"][id$="xyz"]');
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Use filter:

```
$('div')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.id.match(/^abc+xyz$/);
    })
    .html("Matched!")
;
```