# stop multiple selection from a html dropdown

Tags: html

I have a table, in one of the columns I have a `textbox` and a `div` with an `onClick` event on top of the `textbox`, `div` opens(expands) and then when the image in it is selected, or if the user clicks anywhere else on the page, it gets closed.

The problem is, if I open multiple rows and open that `div` in each column, I want all the other divs to get closed automatically, like it happens in the "accordion". How to do it through jquery?

```
<ul class="ul_color_palette" >
<li><img src="img/color_palette/ico_red_sq.png"/> <img src="img/color_palette/ico_blue_sq.png"/></li>  
<li><img src="img/color_palette/ico_red_circle.png"/> <img src="img/color_palette/ico_blue_circle.png"/> </li>  
<li><img src="img/color_palette/ico_red_tri.png"/> <img src="img/color_palette/ico_blue_tri.png"/></li>  
</ul>
```

[image: its a table]

Link [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/GezgW/)

Comment: can you share how the div is opened

Comment: Please post your code... But anyway, I would suggest to simply add something like a "closeall()" function call as the first instruction when opening any div... in order to call any div and then open the one you want

Comment: @ArunPJohny p Jhonyon that particular column click . that dive open. you can see that red selected image

Comment: Call `$('.ul_color_palette').hide()` before you open the div

Comment: @ArunPJohny calling hide() event also hiding the div. any else

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close all of them once the user selects the desired image, just use a proper naming pattern for the ids that you are going to assign to each div that is going to be expanded, then you can use jQuery's `slideUp` function to hide all the DIVs that start with a specific name (Check this link here to understand how to use a `selector` that can refer to multiple DIVs: [Wildcards in jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors)).

Also, check this page here: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/