# How to accept any characters in between * of an getElementById (stack_ * _overflow)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which changes the ID of input fields every time. So for example if I visit the page now, the ID can be `"stack_15_overflow"` and next time it can be `"stack_293_overflow"`.

I want to use a wildcard value for `getElementById`, such as `"stack_ * _overflow"` (where `*` matches anything), to get that value related to any input field starting and ending with some specific text, no matter what text is in between.

**Code:**

```
function HelloId(string){
    var name=string
    document.getElementById('stack_*_overflow').value=name;
}
```

Comment: If you control the HTML use a class and do not do this "weird" selector stuff. Than it is a simple call.

Comment: read this ,it will help also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors

Answer (score 5):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="stack_"][id$="_overflow"]');
```

Comment: Why `querySelectorAll`? This is getting an element by `id`, which should only return 1 element...

Comment: @Ian `*` is a wildcard (in the question). This will select many elements with many different ids.

Comment: @Ian, Well i guess he could have many inputs with different id's following the same pattern. The use of `querySelectorAll` here is more questionnable since the OP uses jQuery already.

Comment: `*` is unrelated and wasn't my point. I missed the text "any input field starting and ending with some specific text" which is the important part

Comment: @plalx Yeah, I misread and didn't see that part I guess?

Comment: @plalx He tagged it jquery, but from his code he showed in the question I'm not so sure he is actually using it. That's why I offered this solution. If he is already using jQuery this is clearly not as nice (and not as cross browser) as undefined's answer.

Comment: @Paulpro, Yeah I agree that he doesn't seem to be using it. Also I am not sure that it's worth to make a copy of the `NodeList`. It's written on MDN that `querySelectorAll` returns a **non-live** `NodeList`.

Comment: @plalx Thanks! I always thought it returned a live list.

Comment: @Paulpro Ian planx and everyone thank you a lot! For some reason it works with querySelector and not querySelectorAll. I refer to JQ for any solutions either in JS or JQ. I use tinymce, have my own made file uploader and want to target a specific input to insert image or video link without to interact with tinymce. On insert image dialog, there is a button which opens my file uploader as modal with iframe, after uploading i have a button. Then onclick onclick="parent.helloId(this.form.foo.value); copy the link and paste it in the targeted input field, which make it happen with the above code.

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery's `attribute starts with` and `attribute ends with` selectors:

```
$("[id^='stack'][id$=overflow]");
```

Note that these selectors are expensive, specifying type of the element can improve the performance:

```
$('element').filter("[id^='stack'][id$=overflow]");
```

Comment: Are you about this "expensiveness"? I'm pretty sure `querySelectorAll` natively supports these attribute selectors, so I don't see why you'd want to force 2 DOM queries by using `.filter()` It would be different for a *custom jQuery selector*. Also, I'm pretty sure the selector is evaluated from right to left, so adding the `element` part doesn't speed anything up, it just filters the result set. I might be wrong about that part though - it might just be when you have a space in the selector, that those parts are evaluated from right to left - but each "group" is evaluated from left to right

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve this by using `getElementById`.
A better solution would be `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`, where you get full support for CSS selectors.

[Reference at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

You will need 2 of these attribute selectors:

Get elements that **start** with a specific string

```
document.querySelector('[id^="stack_"]');
```

Get elements that **contain** a specific string

```
document.querySelector('[id*="stack_"]');
```

Get elements that **ends** with a specific string

```
document.querySelector('[id$="_overflow"]');
```

**By combining ends and starts selectors, you get the following and are able to achieve your desired result:**

```
document.querySelector('[id^="stack_"][id$="_overflow"]');
```

*Happy coding!*

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
$("body:regex(id, stack_[0-9]+_overflow)");
```

[using this plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)