# how to get ids in one go

Tags: jquery, dynatree

This dynatree code. Generating auto generated ids.

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
selectMode:1,
generateIds:true
});
```

These are all li ids of dynatree ul. all ids are autogenerated ids. here i am fetching all li ids to bind on drop event. i want all autogenerated ids in one go. i should not have to specify individual. i want dynamic. anyone.

```
 var obj = $("#dynatree-id-_3,#dynatree-id-_6,#dynatree-id-_7,#dynatree-id-_8,#dynatree-id-_9,#dynatree-id-_10,#dynatree-id-_11,#dynatree-id-_12,#dynatree-id-_13,#dynatree-id-_16,#dynatree-id-_17,#dynatree-id-_18,#dynatree-id-_19,#dynatree-id-_20,#dynatree-id-_21");
```

Comment: Guys Thanks For your valuable answers. But i also need one Constraint. That it should fetch all ids of leaf nodes only. Can anyone explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like `var obj = $("[id^=dynatree-id]")` to get all id's that start with dynatree-id.
See: [Wildcards in jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute selectors:

```
var obj = $('[id^="dynatree"]');
```

---

The above code would get you items which has id started with **dynatree**.

Comment: Your quotes are messed up...you either have to escape the inner quotes with a backslash, or use single-quotes instead of double-quotes.

Comment: @nbrooks oh yes! Actually typing on smaller screens are little difficult, it was really a typo error. For edits thanks to praveen.

Comment: Thanks Jai and praveen for your answers

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

1) create an empty array.
2) iterate over all `li`s.
3) push each id to the array as shown below.
4) Then join the array with comma and use it

```
var ids = [];
$("#tree ul").find("li").each(function () {
    ids.push("#" + this.id);
});

var idsString = ids.join();
//$(idsString)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but when i am using your code my dynatree is vanished.

Comment: Buddy in your code there is one mistake. you forget to write dot (.) before each

Comment: @Paresh3489227 feel free to edit my answers if you find any error :)  Also it would be great if you could share your code in jsfiddle?  so I can correct it

Comment: i was editing but there are some people who angrily vote down. they wont understand the problem of new users. Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

One more solution to this could be -

While assigning the dynamic id's, you can give them a common class, Say class="dynamicLi" and then you wont need to loop through any data item list.

You can simply then use :

```
$(".dynamicLi")
```