# Loop through JSON objects that only start with a certain pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-selectors

What is the correct/idiomatic way to loop through JSON objects that only start with a certain pattern?

Example: say I have a JSON like

```
{
  "END": true, 
  "Lines": "End Reached", 
  "term0": {
    "PrincipalTranslations": {
      // nested data here
    }
  },
  "term1": {
    "PrincipalTranslations": {
      // more nested data here
    }
  }
}
```

I only want to access the `PrincipalTranslations` object and I tried with:

```
$.each(translations, function(term, value) {
    $.each(term, function(pos, value) {
        console.log(pos);
    });
});
```

Which doesn't work, possibly because I can't loop through the `END` and `Lines` objects.

I tried to go with something like

```
$.each(translations, function(term, value) {
    $.each(TERM-THAT-STARTS-WITH-PATTERN, function(pos, value) {
        console.log(pos);
    });
});
```

using [wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors), but without success. I could try to mess up with `if` statements but I suspect there is a nicer solution I'm missing out on. Thanks.

Comment: you can't use wildcards there, $.each simply loops over an array or an object's keys. You'll have to do the filtering using something else, such as an if statement.

Comment: If possible, it would be much easier to change your JSON structure. Can you change the format to contain an array of `terms` instead of each having it's own property?

Comment: FYI, `value` will be the object to iterate over, `term` is the property name. Check the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: I get that JSON as a result of an API request so yep, I could re-arrange the whole thing backend-side. Since I'm new to web dev I just assumed the API was right and the problem was me though :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only interested in the `PrincipalTranslations`-objects, following would do the trick:

```
$.each(translations, function(term, value) {
    if (value.PrincipalTranslations !== undefined) {
        console.log(value.PrincipalTranslations);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvcVN/)

Answer (score 1):

How I would search for a property in an object it is like this:

```
var obj1 ={ /* your posted object*/};


// navigates through all properties
var x = Object.keys(obj1).reduce(function(arr,prop){
// filter only those that are objects and has a property named "PrincipalTranslations"
    if(typeof obj1[prop]==="object" &&  Object.keys(obj1[prop])
        .filter(
            function (p) {
                return p === "PrincipalTranslations";})) {
                     arr.push(obj1[prop]);
                }
    return arr;
},[]);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. If I decide to rearrange the API response, would you say is better to do it client-side as in your example or server-side?

Comment: @laurids this works on any browser older than IE9 and if you polyfill on any browser

Comment: actually I was more concerned about which one is the "good practice" rather than portability ;)

Comment: This approach uses ES5 standards. If you want to use jQuery, Underscore or lodash it will depend on the library to provide "portability" probably about the same coverage these days.