# Get all JSON keys that match a pattern

Tags: javascript, json, regex

Javascript in a browser environment. I wish to get all keys in a JSON object that match a specific pattern. Say, all of them that begin with `mystring`. Is there a simpler/efficient way of doing that without having to iterate through all the keys ?

```
{
   somekey1: "someval1",
   somekey2: "someval2",
   mystringkey1: "someval",
   mystringkey2: "someval"

}
```

There had been similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998293/loop-through-json-objects-that-only-start-with-a-certain-pattern), but a) doesn't fully answer this question and b) JQuery is not an option at the moment.

Comment: The simpler/efficient way is to iterate the keys.

Comment: surely you just do `for (... in ..)` and then test against regex each time...

Comment: That looks like a JavaScript object, but not JSON.

Comment: @Biffen. JSON = JavaScript Object Notation. Is not?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Yes, that's its name. But JSON has a different syntax, compatible with, but not the same as, JavaScript. In this case the names are missing quotes.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes The OP's code does not conform to the JSON grammar; it is not JSON. It *does* conform the JavaScript grammar for objects, however.

Comment: The ES5 way would be something like `Object.keys(yourObjectHere).filter(function(key){return (/^mystring/i).test(key);})`.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes [JSON](http://json.org/)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes okay, thanks.

Comment: @Biffen, yes. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, iterate through your object and add to a result when you find a matching key.

```
var data = {
   somekey1: "someval1",
   somekey2: "someval2",
   mystringkey1: "someval",
   mystringkey2: "someval"
}

var filtered = {}

for (key in data) {
    if (key.match(/^mystring/)) filtered[key] = data[key];
}

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var myObj = {
  somekey1: "someval1",
  somekey2: "someval2",
  mystringkey1: "someval",
  mystringkey2: "someval"

};

var pattern = /^mystring/;
var matchingKeys = Object.keys(myObj).filter(function(key) {
  return pattern.test(key);
});

console.log(matchingKeys);
```