# Selecting a div tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div id = "_login_mack_facebook">some text</div>
<div id = "_login_robin_facebook">some text</div>
<div id = "_login_robert_facebook">some text</div>
```

and so on How can select all div of  **"_login_sometext_facebook"**   using javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors

Comment: @gdahl OP is not asking for jQuery solution.

Comment: Use a second attribute, like `class`, or `data-*`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `document.querySelectorAll` and class expression to get all ids starting with (`^`) **_login** + ending in (`$`) **facebook** for this.
Try:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="_login"][id$="facebook"]')
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/385Ew/1/)

Answer (score -3):

```
var div = document.getElementById("_login_1_facebook");
var div1 = document.getElementById("_login_2_facebook");
var div2 = document.getElementById("_login_3_facebook");
```

Using loop in javascript and access all div replase sometext using loop variable like:

document.getElementById("*login***a**_facebook");

Comment: if there are hundreds of like that how you will select it