# Bookmarklet to auto fill textarea with random element name

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I am trying to build a bookmarklet to auto-fill the textarea with attribute `name="param[random-number][details]"` with text.

[image]

The `random-number` is generated on the server and is different each time. The page HTML looks like:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Video Title:</td>                                                
<td>                            
<input type="text" name="param[30301754][title]" value="VIDEO TITLE" autocomplete="on">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>File name:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="param[30301754][filename]" value="FILE NAME" autocomplete="on">.3gp
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description: </td>
<td><textarea name="param[30301754][description]"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Auto fill it with text from where?

Comment: Also, are you building the bookmarklet yourself?

Comment: @jack like var text = {'text i want to insert on textarea'},

Comment: @NateBarbettini no, I mean someone can build me, because i dont know javascript language :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For future reference, "can someone build this for me" is not generally a good reason for a question here. We like to answer specific questions, not write code on request. People will be much more receptive if you mention what you've already tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's only one element like `<textarea name="param[xxx][description]">` on the page, you can use a [jQuery wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors) as a selector.

```
$("textarea[name$=\\[description\\]]").val("test");
```

---

**Update**

To do this as a simple bookmarklet, you'll need to prompt the user for the text they want to auto-populate (or get it from somewhere else), and wrap the whole thing in an anonymous function. You also need a reference to the jQuery library. (See [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154) for more information on how to create a bookmarklet.)

This should do it for your case:

```
javascript: (function () {
    if (!($ = window.jQuery)) {
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js';
        script.onload = doAutoFill;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    } else {
        doAutoFill();
    }

    function doAutoFill() {
        var textToFill = prompt("Enter text to fill:");
        if (textToFill != null) $("textarea[name$=\\[description\\]]").val(textToFill);
    }
})();
```

Here's an updated fiddle as an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5rrqhzL/5/)

Comment: Updated my example with a working bookmarklet. Let me know if it does what you are looking for.

Comment: yes, its work! you're awesome nate, thanks so much :D
but it cant automatically filled :(

Comment: No problem, glad that worked! :) btw, you can upvote the answer as well as accept it.

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. No worries!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your bookmarklets button so I'm making some assumptions. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j61Lhmra/)

```
var someText = "text for the textbox";
$('#myButtonId').on('click', function(){
  $('textarea').val(someText);
});
```

Comment: but it have a random number on name (name="param[random-number][details]")

Comment: Why does it need to be random? If there's only one textbox on the page you can give it an Id, the name won't matter.

Comment: because it name had been randomized from server

Comment: yes, just only one textbox but i cant give it an id, because the page are generated from server automatically

Comment: I updated my code, you still have to have some way of attaching the click handler to the button though.

Comment: This still can not :(