# Why wildcard selectors do not trigger with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code:

```
$doc.find('#g').on('click', function(e) { 
   $target = $doc.find('#g form');
   $target.toggle();
   $doc.find('#g input[type="text"]').focus();
});
```

I want it to stop triggering on children so this works:

```
$doc.find('#g form').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

So using `#g form` works, but selectors like `#g *` or `#g>*` or `.children()` do not work, why?

The html structure is like this:

```
<div id="g" title="look up">
<i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
<i class="fa fa-search-minus" style="display: none"></i>
    <div></div>
    <form><div>
            <input>
            <input>
            <input>
            <input>
          </div>
    <input><input><input></form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is wildcard? what you trying to do?

Comment: need to see html structure. We don't know what `children` there are for example and `#g *` is very different than `#g>*`. Really need to improve question with more code and expectations of what you want the code to do or what it isn't doing properly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors

Comment: @XGreen link is not a duplicate. This question is asking about a css selector ([universal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) or child), the other is asking about a wildcard that jQuery will parse and match regex like. There may be a way to use such jQuery wildcard to find all children of the `#g` element, but that would be a worthy answer to this question.

Comment: I can't see where I have suggested it was a duplicate. I found a useful link and thought provide as comment and perhaps would be useful.

Comment: seems to work for me, what is doc referencing? maybe the behavior is not working, try just running the selector.

Comment: there isn't one html is pretty much that just another div then body tag