# How to add wildcard to CSS selectors?

Tags: javascript, php, function

I am working on a website and I am trying to figure out how to add a wildcard to the following code for `author1_name`:

```js
$(function() {
  var num = 2;
  var id = 'author' + num;
  var uni_id = 'university' + num;
  $("#AuthorFieldButton").click(function() {
    var name = 'Author ' + num;
    var uni_name = 'University ' + num;
    id = 'author' + num;
    $('.author-group').last().after('<div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="' + id + '">' + name + ':</label><div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" id="' + id + '" name="' + id + '" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="40" ></div></div><div class="form-group author-remove-group author-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="' + uni_id + '">' + uni_name + ':</label><div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" id="' + uni_id + '" name="' + uni_id + '" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="55" ></div></div>')
    num++;
  });
  $("#article_name").autocomplete({
    source: 'articlesearch.php'
  });

  $("#author1_name").autocomplete({
    source: 'authorsearch.php'
  });
  $("#author2_name").autocomplete({
    source: 'authorsearch.php'
  });
  $("#author3_name").autocomplete({
    source: 'authorsearch.php'
  });
  $("#author4_name").autocomplete({
    source: 'authorsearch.php'
  });
  $("#author5_name").autocomplete({
    source: 'authorsearch.php'
  });
  $("#author6_name").autocomplete({
    source: 'authorsearch.php'
  });
  $("#author1_university").autocomplete({
    source: 'universitysearch.php'
  });
  $("#author2_university").autocomplete({
    source: 'universitysearch.php'
  });
  $("#author3_university").autocomplete({
    source: 'universitysearch.php'
  });
  $("#author4_university").autocomplete({
    source: 'universitysearch.php'
  });
  $("#author5_university").autocomplete({
    source: 'universitysearch.php'
  });
  $("#author6_university").autocomplete({
    source: 'universitysearch.php'
  });
});
```

I'd like it to place a wildcard to the number in the `author1_name` and `author1_university` so that I don't have to repeat the selector multiple times in my code. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you give the elements a specific class, like class="author_name" then call the $(".author_name").autocomplete(...)

Comment: @JohnBoker I thought of that but didn't know if it was proper practice to add tons of different class names to single elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildcards in jQuery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors)

Comment: I dont see any harm in adding classes to specific elements here.

Comment: @JohnBoker Well I just realized this is actually based off of the element id not the class....

Comment: another option if you don't want to use classes is to use a for loop. Something like... `for (var i=1;i<=6;i++) {
$("#author"+i+"_name").autocomplete({
    source: 'authorsearch.php'
  });
}` and then repeat that for the university one.

Comment: @TaylorClark John Boker is suggesting that you add the classes as well to make it easier to select. In actuality, though, if you want to keep your current configuration you should be able to do this `$("[id^='author'][id$='_university']")`

Comment: @iismathwizard what is the most common practice? Sorry I am new to this

Comment: To be honest, since they're all related elements I would expect them to share a class (for styling purposes). Personally, I would put a `author_university` class on each one of those and then use jquery as so `$(".author_university")` since it would make more sense.

Comment: @TaylorClark I'll post an answer with the contents of my comment so you can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two routes here:

1. You can put a single class on each of the like elements.

   `class="author_university"`

   JQuery: `$(".author_university")`
2. Or use a selector for id like so:

   `$("[id^='author'][id$='_university']")`

   This selects any element with an `id` starting with `"author"` and ending with `"_university"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the selector like this:

```
$("[id^=author]").autocomplete({
    source: 'universitysearch.php'
  });
```

This finds the ids which starts with `author`.

To find the ids that end with `_university` :

```
$("[id$=_university]").autocomplete({
    source: 'universitysearch.php'
  });
```

Adding a separate class to all the elements you need to select also is a solution. You can add the class `author_of_university` to the elements and select like:

```
$(".author_of_university").autocomplete({
        source: 'universitysearch.php'
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a "starts with" selector:

```
$( "[id^='author']" ).autocomplete({});
```