# Trigger an event on different time of the same class JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please suggest an edit in the title as I'm not able to understand what should I name it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class='portfolio'>
      <h2 class='mainheading'>
        Recent From
        <span class='welcome-heading'>Portfolio</span>
      </h2>
      <hr>
      <div class='portfolio-row'>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio1' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-1'></div>
            <div class='back back-1'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio2' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-2'></div>
            <div class='back back-2'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio3' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-3'></div>
            <div class='back back-3'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio4' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-4'></div>
            <div class='back back-4'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio5' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-5'></div>
            <div class='back back-5'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio6' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-6'></div>
            <div class='back back-6'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio7' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-7'></div>
            <div class='back back-7'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio8' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-8'></div>
            <div class='back back-8'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio9' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-9'></div>
            <div class='back back-9'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio10' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-10'></div>
            <div class='back back-10'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio11' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-11'></div>
            <div class='back back-11'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio12' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-12'></div>
            <div class='back back-12'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio13' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-13'></div>
            <div class='back back-13'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio14' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-14'></div>
            <div class='back back-14'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio15' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-15'></div>
            <div class='back back-15'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flip-container portfolio-for-transition jstransitionportfolio16' ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
          <div class='flipper'>
            <div class='front front-16'></div>
            <div class='back back-16'>
              <p>Some Portfolio Website</p>
              <a href=''>Visit</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var xScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(xScroll > $('.our-services-item1').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.our-services-item1').addClass('is-showing-our-services');
        },150);
    };
  var yScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(yScroll > $('.our-services-item2').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.our-services-item2').addClass('is-showing-our-services');
        },150);
    };
  var aScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(aScroll > $('.our-services-item3').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.our-services-item3').addClass('is-showing-our-services');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.our-services-item4').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.our-services-item4').addClass('is-showing-our-services');
        },150);
    };

  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio1').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio1').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio2').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio2').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio3').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio3').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio4').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio4').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio5').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio5').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio6').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio6').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio7').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio7').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio8').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio8').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio9').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio9').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio10').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio10').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio11').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio11').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio12').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio12').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio13').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio13').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio14').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio14').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio15').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio15').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
  var zScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if(zScroll > $('.jstransitionportfolio16').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.jstransitionportfolio16').addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio');
        },150);
    };
```

As you can see that these things are of the same class but I have to name them differently so the trigger is not fired for every element of the same class so I named them jstransitionportfolio[1-16]. But it increases my script time alot. I want to combine them in the single function so it decreases my script time, plus i won't have alot of classes and my code will be cleaner and nicer. Please help!

Comment: when you start your function?! I mean,  you do all this **if**  on page load, on windows scroll, or when?

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: Use widlcards - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors

Comment: @UmerJaved but the class **is-showing** needs to be removed after I scroll all the body, or has to remain?

Comment: You should simply attach the event to a common class and use $(this) to make it work for each element

Comment: @UmerJaved your class must remain with different numbers? if yes I have to review my answer.

Comment: Nope. It won't remain with different numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be simplified :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var xScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    $(".some-class").each(function() {
        var that = this;
        if(xScroll > $(that).offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(that).addClass('some-other-class');
            },150);
        }
    });
});
```

You just have to change `.some-class` and `some-other-class` to some class name of your choosing.

Side note : Please be carefull when adding thing to the `onScroll` listener, at it will degrade the user experience, by slowing the scroll.

Comment: Thanks alot man. It really worked for me and my code is much cleaner now. And easy to understand too :)

Answer (score 0):

Before using this function, remove the numbers from your **our-services-item** and **jstransitionportfolio** classes. You can check the **[demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/5h3gp35u/1/)**

```
var setHeight=$(window).height() / 1.2;
var ourServices=$('.our-services-item');
var tranPortfolio=$('.jstransitionportfolio');

$(window).on('scroll',function(){

  var xScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  ourServices.each(function(){
     var el=$(this);
     if(xScroll>(el.offset().top-setHeight))
      setTimeout(function(){el.addClass('is-showing-our-services')},150);
  });

  tranPortfolio.each(function(){
     var el=$(this);
     if(xScroll>(el.offset().top-setHeight))
      setTimeout(function(){el.addClass('is-showing-jstransitionportfolio')},150);
  });

});
```