# CSS class selector jQuery with specific Class name

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to get Class starting with specific string in jQuery

```
<li class="active cc-1">A1</li>
<li class="cc-2">B1</li>
<li class="cc-ab amimate-me">C1</li>
```

how can I select class starts with **"cc-ANYTHING"** ON CLICK of `"<li>"`

```
$('li').on('click', function(e){
  alert($(this).attr('class^="cc-*"'));
});
```

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method using `.attr('class')` together with `Array.prototype.filter()` :

```js
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
    var classlist = $(this).attr('class');
    if (classlist === undefined) { // check if li doesn't have a class attribute
     return false;
    }

    // filter and return the class if it starts with 'cc-'
    var ccClass = classlist.split(' ').filter((v, i) => (v.startsWith('cc-')));
    console.log(ccClass);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="active cc-1">A1</li>
    <li class="cc-2">B1</li>
    <li class="cc-ab amimate-me">C1</li>
    <li>D1</li>
    <li class="animate-me">E1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property to iterate the collection of the class attributes of the element. and [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) can be used to test.

Here in the example, since multiple class can fulfill the condition `Array` is used.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('li').on('click', function(e) {
    var arr = []
    for (var i = 0; i < this.classList.length; i++) {
      var item = this.classList.item(i);
      if (item.startsWith("cc-")) {
        arr.push(item);
      }
    }
    
    console.clear();
    console.log(arr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active cc-1">A1</li>
  <li class="cc-2">B1</li>
  <li class="cc-ab amimate-me">C1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good Technique *classList

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the star after the double quotes like this,

```
alert($(this).attr('class^="cc-"*'));
```