# Get values of data-* attributes without knowing what follows after "data-"

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I want to get data-* (data dash, or dataset) values without knowing what follows after the dash.
Ex:

```
<div data-whatever="value" data-another="value2"></div>
```

I don't know how the "whatever" or "another" parts are named, but I need to grab the value. 
Is it possible with JavaScript?

Because

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-*]')
```

is not a valid selector

Comment: Not sure this is supported natively, but you can do this with jQuery or another utility library. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5376431/3966682

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dataset` property of an element contains all the `data-*` attributes. This is a `DOmStringMap` whose keys are the attributes with the `data-` removed and the remaining words converted to camelCase.

I don't think there's a way to select just the elements with any data attribute, so you'll have to select all elements and filter them yourself by checking the length of `element.dataset`.

```
var dataElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*')).filter(el => Object.keys(el.dataset).length > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

In the example I've created an Id for the `div`

```
<div data-whatever="value" data-another="value2" id="test"></div>
```

And after I got the element by Id, retrieving the `dataset` property which returned an `DOMStringMap`

```
data = document.getElementById('test').dataset;
console.log(data);
```

And finally I just got the keys from the returned object.

```
Object.keys(data).map(function(el) {
    console.log(el)
});
```

I hope it helps you :)