# Select all the inputs with name attribute contain Substring - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select all the inputs with name attribute end with `*Name`.

I have 6 inputs type text with name :

- deviceName
- profileName
- ssidName
- captiveName
- trafficName
- sessionName

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="deviceName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="profileName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="ssidName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="captiveName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="trafficName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="sessionName">
```

I'm trying to prevent any space enter on those 5 inputs

I've tried

```
$("input[name='*Name']").keyup(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
});
```

My selection doesn't seem to take any effects.

Comment: `$("input[name$='Name']").`

Comment: please explain how you come up with that !

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildcards in jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors)

Answer (score 3):

Just a small error in your code with the [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) -

Change:

```
$("input[name='*Name']")
```

to

```
$("input[name*='Name']")
```

Check [this JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wimiqujuna/edit?html,js,output) for playing around.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the correct selector but in the wrong place.

you need to use it like so `$("input[name*='Name']")`

See the link to jquery documentation. https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

To select element ending with attribute value 'Name' use `$("input[name$='Name']")` - https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/.

```js
$("input[name$='Name']").keyup(function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="deviceName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="profileName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="ssidName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="captiveName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="trafficName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="sessionName">
```

Note - If you want to make attribute selector case-insensitive add `i` before closing square bracket i:e `$("input[name$='name' i]")`.

```js
console.log($("input[name$='name' i]"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="deviceName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="profileName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="ssidName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="captiveName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="trafficName">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="sessionName">
```