# How can I use some jQuery id with less line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I search to reduce the size of this type of jQuery content with 24 `id`s:

```
if (currValue >= 3) /* These are my 24 ids */
{
    document.getElementById("skillbutton1").disabled  = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton2").disabled  = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton3").disabled  = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton4").disabled  = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton5").disabled  = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton6").disabled  = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton7").disabled  = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton8").disabled  = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton9").disabled  = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton10").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton11").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton12").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton13").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton14").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton15").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton15").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton16").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton17").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton18").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton19").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton20").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton21").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton22").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton23").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("skillbutton24").disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: `$('[id^="skillbutton"]').prop('disabled', true);`.

Comment: Or use a `class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the same class on every one of those elements and loop through them:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.skillbutton').forEach(el => el.disabled = true);
```

Or the same thing in jQuery:

```
$('.skillbutton').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all the elements starting with "skillbutton" you should use:

```
$("[id^=skillbutton]")
```

To get those that end with "skillbutton"

```
$("[id$=skillbutton]")
```

Or use a common class as one comment mentions:

```
<button id="skillbutton1" class="skillBtn">Btn</button>
$(".skillBtn")
```

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors) for context