# How do I use querySelector to target a hash at the end of an anchor tag's href attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, queryselector

I need to use `querySelector` to target and match hashes in my anchor tags to another function but the hash occurs at the end of the url. How do I go about this? I'm trying to use the wildcard  to match but its not working (returning error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of null`)... Basically just need to query everything after the hash. Thanks for any insight.

```
<a href="example.abc.org/#xyz">

var newLink = document.querySelector(`[href*='#${id}']`).classList.add('current');
```

Edit: replaced with dollar sign to catch end of string but still no luck... Here's the full code for context. I'm trying to create an Intersection Observer.

```
<a href="example.abc.org/#xyz">

const nav = (entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.55) {
          document.querySelector('li.current').classList.remove('current');
          const id = entry.target.getAttribute('id');
          var newLink = document.querySelector(`[href$='#${id}']`).classList.add('current');
        }
      });
    }
    const options = {
      root: null
    };
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(nav,options);
    // target the elements to be observed
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section.op-section');
    sections.forEach((section) => {observer.observe(section);});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors

Comment: Try `<a href="example.abc.org/#xyz">` (was missing quotes around `href`).

Comment: Thanks but that's only an example — the actual anchor is generated in the backend. I'll fix for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw my mistake: class `current` was attached to the list-item not anchor. Thanks.