# When you write a program to toggle all checkboxes, is there a way to not include other checkboxes outside of that group?

Tags: javascript, html

I understand how to toggle the status of all check-boxes to checked or not-checked by a single click, either by a check-box or a link.  That is the easy part.

But I also have several check-boxes that I do not want to toggle on or off by a single click, that are not part of the group that should be affected. These check-boxes need to be protected.

Below is an example.  I can click the bottom checkbox to toggle, but it should only affect Item 1 through Item 3 check-boxes. When I click the bottom checkbox, it should not toggle the first two check-boxes that should be protected.

Thanks...

```js
$(function() {
  $('#toggle-all').click(function(event) {

    var selected = this.checked;
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = selected;
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- These next two checkboxes should not be part of the checkboxes to be all toggled on or off -->

<input type='checkbox' name='notAssociated1'>This checkbox should be protected from ability to toggle all below<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='notAssociated2'>This checkbox should also be protected from ability to toggle all below<br><br>

<!-- The checkboxes below should be affected by clicking on the checkbox to toggle all on or off -->

<input type="checkbox" name="CB1" id="CB1" />Item 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="CB2" id="CB2" />Item 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="CB3" id="CB3" />Item 3<br>

<!-- select all boxes -->

<br><input type="checkbox" name="toggle-all" id="toggle-all" />Toggle Item 1 thru Item 3 but not the top two checkboxes
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Wildcards in jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors)

Comment: Of course there is, yes. But how do you want to identify the elements that *should* be affected? By their `name`, by a common class-name, by a custom `data-*` attribute? Where should that come from? Or do you plan to exclude elements based on information (such as that, above)?

Answer (score 0):

With a slight modification to your code, you can enable selecting only the `checkbox` inputs you want. There are multiple ways to achieve this, but I chose to surround the targeted check boxes with a `fieldset` element (you can use a `div` element or other block-level element if you wish) and use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select only these check boxes. See the following code snippet as an example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#toggle-all').click(function(event) {
    var selected = this.checked;
    $(this).siblings(":checkbox").each(function() {
      this.checked = selected;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- These next two checkboxes should not be part of the checkboxes to be all toggled on or off -->
<fieldset>
  <input type='checkbox' name='notAssociated1'>This checkbox should be protected from ability to toggle all below<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='notAssociated2'>This checkbox should also be protected from ability to toggle all below<br><br>
</fieldset>

<!-- The checkboxes below should be affected by clicking on the checkbox to toggle all on or off -->

<fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CB1" id="CB1" />Item 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CB2" id="CB2" />Item 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CB3" id="CB3" />Item 3<br>

  <!-- select all boxes -->

  <br><input type="checkbox" name="toggle-all" id="toggle-all" />Toggle Item 1 thru Item 3 but not the top two checkboxes
</fieldset>
```

If you would prefer to keep the original layout, you can use other selectors to target the selectors you want. In your case, you can select with `$("[id^=CB]")` or setting classes to each of the check box elements and selecting with `$(".selectAllCB")` or whatever class name you would like.

Comment: Wow.  I had no idea a field set would do that.  Thank you so much for your knowledge.

Comment: If this helped solve the issue, please mark this answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using jQuery selectors you can just give checkboxes groupings through id, or class.
eg. using:

```
$('.class-group')...
```

(bit of a noob myself mind!)

Comment: This is not an answer, it should (at best) be written as a comment to the question; yes, I know you don't have the "comment everywhere," privilege yet, but that doesn't mean that comments are acceptable in the answer-space of a question. Please: wait until you've earned 50 points of reputation before trying to comment. Also, I do remember how frustrating it is to have to wait for others to ask for detail while unable to do so myself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I actually finally got it to work with classes.  Each checkbox Item 1 to 3 I added class="group".  Then I added $('.group:checkbox') and it seems to work.  Unless someone has a better idea.  But thanks for the tip.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).