# match dates with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, phpquery

I want to match these tags:

```
<div>03-24-2010</div>
<div>04-23-2011</div>
```

With jquery:

```
("div:contains([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})")
```

What do I need to do to the regular expression here to make it work (using phpquery - php implementation of jquery)?

Comment: See [JQuery selector regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Comment: would it be possible to modify the HTML and add a class? that of course would make things easier. or maybe a parent element will always have a class that you could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var divs = $("div").filter(function(){
return /[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}/.test($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: change `.val()` to `.text()` and that will work, http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/3MjzD/

Comment: I'm using phpquery, which is a php implementation of jquery. My mind isn't translating that into the correct php. The part i'm hung up on is the .test. Is that part of jquery? I don't see it in the documentation.

Comment: @JMC: test is part of Javascript Regular Expression. I am not aware of phpquery.. Let me look at thr phpquery doc to see if I can further update the answer

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't support regex selectors out of the box. You need to use a plugin in or something like http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/ (a filter)

Comment: Not the downvoter, but unfortunately I can't add any extensions to my implementation.

Comment: @Neal You can use regex in a filter to return something, ok, but there is no regex selecting like JMC is tying to do. `:contains()` takes a simple string only.

Comment: @Neal, the answer didn't say you can't do regex, it said there's no regex selector.  You can undownvote now because it's been edited.

Comment: @JMC, my second example of  is not an extension per se. Just a function you can use.