# jQuery: caseless selector search?

Tags: jquery

For example searching

```
$('[name=whatever]')
```

should find

```
 $('[name=whatever]') and  $('[name=WhaTevEr]')
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any possible solution is going to be really inefficient, because it cannot work with the browser's native selector engine.  It would be better to use a class to identify the elements.

However, if you're insistent on this approach, you can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('[name]').filter(function () {
    return this.name.toLowerCase() == "whatever";
});
```

Comment: +1 Character for character the same as the code I was about to click "post" on!

Comment: @lonesomeday: if I had a penny for every time that happened to me... ;-)

Comment: Great solution, simple and efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can have a regex as selector

Take a look at this topic:

[jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)