# Making partial matches with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to find all input boxes with `id` containing `_date`

My code is like this:

```
<input type="text" name="creation_date" id="id_creation_date" />
```

Can I use regex for that? Do I need to install something extra for regex to work with jQuery?

Comment: I don think you can directly do that way.
What I think you can do is . get all the input using $('input') and then filtering out using a regex and $(this).attr('id')

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery selector regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Comment: Its better to have this link [http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I'm thinking of one of [these](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)...

`$('input[id*="_date"]').css('background-color', 'red');`

Comment: thanks buddy that is working , but will it work on all browsers like ie7

Comment: Yes it will, as jquery is taking care of cross browser compatibility.

Comment: It should, as far as I know, even though it uses CSS3-like selectors, it breaks down to this line as I see it in the jQuery source code: `f==="*="?e.indexOf(g)>=0:f==="~=`... meaning it's literally doing a simple (cross-browser) indexOf() check on the specified attribute.

Comment: This is beautiful :)

Answer (score 22):

If you just want to check ending with "_date" rather than containing "_date" you can use

```
$('input[id$="_date"]')
```