# How can I loop through all tags having different ids in jquery?

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

I want to iterate through my django formset which has ids using jquery.

```
id="id_lines-0-label"
id="id_lines-0-description"
id="id_lines-1-label" 
id="id_lines-1-description"
id="id_lines-2-label"
id="id_lines-2-description"
id="id_lines-3-label"
id="id_lines-3-description
# and so on.
```

There is an add button which adds forms to formset. so it should only iterate though the forms that are added.

I have updated my question. My html has field label and description which has ids as shown above and i want to select only the field which has label in its id.

Comment: try this `$("[id^='#id_lines-']")`, this will select all elements starting with `#id_lines-0` also are you sure the id starts with `#` ?

Comment: `$('[id^="id_lines"]').each(function() { //your function });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making partial matches with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488942/making-partial-matches-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `substring` selector to get all the elements with a given substring. For an example lets say we have a `div` with those `id` then you can use `div[id*='id_lines-']` selector to get all the elements with that pattern:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "div[id*='id_lines-']" ).each(function(index){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    //select only label with id that has label text in its id
    if(id.indexOf('-label') !== -1){
      $(this).html('This is selected label id = '+id);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="#id_lines-0-label"></div>
<div id="#id_lines-0-description"></div>
<div id="#id_lines-2-label"></div>
<div id="#id_lines-3-description"></div>
<div id="#id_lines-3-label"></div>
<div id="#id_lines-3-description"></div>
<div id="#id_lines-3-label"></div>
```

Comment: I have updated my question please feel free to update you're answer.