# How to execute partial find on dynamic HTML5 data descriptor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find, partial

I have a series of images tagged with HTML5 data descriptor "data-type2=[x]" where x is a number of different elements.

e.g.

```
    <img data-type2="pants" class="element" src="#>
```

I am trying to pass that data field into a jquery function that finds classes in another div `(<div class="outfit-list")` that has child divs tagged with classes such as:

```
    <div class="pants-001">
    <div class="pants-002">
    <div class="shoes-001">
```

etc.

Here is where I am stumped: how do I write a jquery function that accesses data type2 from the item I click (e.g. data-type2="pants"), finds all other divs under .outfit-list with classes that have, for example, "pants" in their class name "pants-002", and hide them? The function I have below does not work - I suspect that's because it's looking for the full name and not partial.

How do I make it perform a partial search to locate the classes that contain the term from data-type2?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.thumbslist .element').click(function(){
                $('.outfit-list').find('.'+$(this).data('type2')).hide();
              });
            }); 
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), `[attribute*="value"]`.

```
$('.outfit-list').find('[class*="' + $(this).data('type2') + '"]').hide();
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems like the simplest solution of them all and now my function is working nicely. I am going to follow up on all the other replies soon and test each of them out as well to understand how they work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`starts with`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector. Something like

```
$(".thumbslist .element").click(function() {
    var type2 = $(this).data("type2");
    $(".outfit-list").find("div[class^=" + type2 + "]").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin adds support for data selectors: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dataSelector

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the jQuery .data() method is amazing: http://api.jquery.com/data/

You could do:

```
$("#img1").data('type', 'pants')
// Or whatever else you need to attach data to. You can do this dynamically too!

t = $("#img1").data('type')
// Recall that data at some point

$("div").each(function() {
  pat = new RegExp(t)
  if ($(this).attr('class').search(pat) !== -1) {
    $(this).hide()
  }
});
```

Or even better in [Coffeescript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/)

```
t = $("#img1").data 'type'
$("div").each ->
  if ($(@).attr('class').search new RegExp t) isnt -1 then $(@).hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

May be with something like in this other question

[jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You could just grab the value of the attribute then use it in an attribute selector: http://jsfiddle.net/n73fC/1/