# Write a jquery selector to select a class with a certain pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I select some divs with class name pattern `a-<random>-c`.

Comment: use regular expression for that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may find useful information [**Here**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

for your case this might work

```
$("div:regex(class, .a*c)").jqFunction()
```

for matching the starting of selector string

```
<script>$('input[name^="txt"]').val('content here!');</script>
```

this Finds all inputs with an attribute name that starts with 'txt' and puts text in them.

```
<script>
$("div:contains('new')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
    </script>
```

Finds all divs containing "new" and underlines them.

```
<script>$('[name$="address"]').val('a letter');</script>
```

Finds all inputs with an attribute name that ends with 'address' and puts text in them.

Combination of these may be helpful to you see if it helps

Comment: You may also find this SO post useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: old question and answer, but just want to add that of course `$(div[class^="text"])` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [standard selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that meets the needs of your pattern e.g. Starts With, Contains, Ends With, or you can use the [Regex](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) selector plugin from James Padolsey to match based on a regular expression.