# jQuery:How to select elements with particular class here?

Tags: jquery

HTML goes like this:

```
<span class="someClass position1" >span1</span>
<span class="someClass" >span2</span>
<span class="someClass" >span3</span>
<span class="someClass position2" >span4</span>
<span class="someClass" >span5</span>
<span class="someClass position4" >span6</span>
<span class="someClass position10" >span7</span>
<span class="someClass" >span8</span>
<span class="someClass position12" >span9</span>
```

Now, using jQuery, how will I change the `backgroundColor` of only those elements which have the class `position`+**SomeINTEGER**?

I want to select all the elements with the class `poistion`+TheRespectiveInteger

Comment: Do you want that for one specific integer only (that would be easy), or for every possible integer?

Comment: No, I want to select all those classes which have position+someIntegers

Comment: @JanDvorak every possible integer.

Comment: see for your soluion http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you want to change the background of **all** the elements that have a class matching that pattern - not just for one particular number.

There is probably a **hacky** way to do this by treating `class` as just another attribute and doing a partial match against the value.

However a better solution is to add another class that you can select on. Perhaps have whatever is adding the `positionX` classes also add a `positioned` class at the same time.

Comment: As an extra : if you use a `positioned` class, you can simply use the css stylesheet to set the background color.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('.someClass').filter(function () {
    return /(\s|^)position[0-9]+(\s|$)/.test(this.className);
}).css('background-color', 'silver');
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/XYUU6/3/)

You can just modify the regex to get the perfect result :)

Comment: I'd also suggest adding a class instead of setting the background color directly.

Comment: What about `position12`? What about `position1A`?

Comment: @JanDvorak I just gave idea to OP. he/she can update the regex to get the perfect result. I mentioned this in the post. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green hack in the sense of using the wrong tool (regex, instead of adding a class)

Comment: @Mr_Green It's probably the best way of answering the questions as written - but it's still treating `class` as just an attribute and doing a text match against it, instead of using classes as they were intended.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".someClass").each(function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; ++i)
    {
        if (classes[i].match(/^position\d+$/i)) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    }
});
```

For any elements containing a class that is `positionN` where `N` is any integer as well as `someClass` class, if you must do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/ysUMs/2/

Comment: Kinda hacky, but rigid :-)

Comment: +1 for "If you must do this". Unlike most of the hacky solutions that popped up below, this one should actually work.

Comment: I'd also suggest adding a class instead of setting the background color directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following selector:

```
$("span:regex(class, (\s|^)position[0-9]+(\s|$))").css("background-color", "Green");
```

For more reference, see [Write a jquery selector to select a class with a certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742603/write-a-jquery-selector-to-select-a-class-with-a-certain-pattern)

For `regex` selector, you need to write following line of code:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
    validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
    attr = {
        method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                    matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
        property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
    },
    regexFlags = 'ig',
    regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
```

this [wonderfull implementation](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) given by **James Padolsey**.

see working example : http://jsfiddle.net/Q7fTW/16/

Comment: I can't see any `:regex` selector in the jQuery documentation. That answer you linked refers to a specific plugin that needs to be included before this can be used: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Comment: You need to include defination for `regex` selector. See my edited code.

Comment: I don't know enough about this custom regex selector to comment authoritatively, but I suspect this does not work as written. Why do you have a `.` if you're matching against the class attribute? How do you prevent selecting a `positioning` class? What happens if `position` is the first class in the attribute value? What about if it's not the first?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32127/discussion-between-sanjeevrai-and-jcsanyi)

Comment: Having seen the plugin uses real regexes: no, that regex is not correct.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, in which scenario does it fails?

Comment: @SanjeevRai still wrong. `/position*/` matches `positio`, `position`, `positionnnnn` and such. This will find any element whose class list contains `positio`

Comment: @SanjeevRai still wrong. `unposition1` and `position1A` will still test positive

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, I don't have much idea of regular expression, can you modify the part of regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".position" + someINTEGER).css('backgroundColor','your color');
```

**EDIT**:

The way you asked the question is quite confusing.

To identify the elements which have a class position + Integer, you need to specify another class to them for identification

```
<span class="someClass integerclass position1" >span1</span>
<span class="someClass integerclass position2" >span4</span>

$(".integerclass).css('backgroundColor','your color');
```

Comment: And what is `someINTEGER`?

Comment: @NavneetSaini I thought you had one?

Comment: the integer you want to put there, like $(".position" + 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        if( $(".someClass").hasClass(".position"+NUMBER) ){
            $(this).css({ 'backgroundColor','your color' });
        } 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `hasClass` over a set does not do what you think, and `$(this)` is not you think where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

it's working

```
    $('[class^="someClass position"]').css({ 'background-color': 'red' })
    //Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.
```

or

```
    $('[class*="position"]').css({ 'background-color': 'red' })
    //Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring.
```

or

```
    $('[class^="someClass"][class*=" position"]').css({ 'background-color': 'red' })
    //Matches elements that match all of the specified attribute filters.
```

refrence

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: This will also match anything with a `positioned` or `notpositioned` or `needsposition` class as well.

Comment: Try anyone out of this as your requirement for solve this problem.

Comment: The problem is there's no guarantee which order the classes will show up in in the attribute value when they're dynamically added/removed. That's in addition to the fact that you're not checking for numbers at all - these classes could be followed by anything, and they'd still be selected.

Comment: Stll wrong. Option#1 is too specific (you can't swap the classes, add a new one to the beginning...) and also it matches `positioned` et al. #2 matches `positioned`, `unpositionable` et al. #3 breaks if the `positionX` class is first, and it also matches `positioned`

Comment: But @Navneet Saini as per your problem one of this solution can solve it

Answer (score -2):

If you know the value of SomeINTEGER then use :

```
  $(".position" + SomeINTEGER).css('backgroundColor','red');
```

else     // This suggests starting from "position"

```
 $('span[class^=position]).css('backgroundColor','red');
```

Comment: Your first solution doesn't actually answer the question - they **don't** know the integer. The second solution assumes that the position class is the first class that the element has - which can't be guaranteed.