# JQuery: how to write a selector to find elements with a class ending with a given substring?

Tags: jquery, selector

I use JQuery for my web application. I don't know how to write a selector for this situation.

```
<a class="abc def xyz-delete-confirm efg">text</a>

<a class="abc def delete-confirm">text</a>
```

I need to find all links that has a class ending with "-delete-confirm" or has a class called "delete-confirm".

I know how to handle the situation of having a class called "delete-confirm". How about the "-delete-confirm situation"? Can I have a single selector covering two situations?

Thanks for any input!

Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine them like this.

```
var $allofthem = $('[class$="-delete-confirm"],.delete-confirm');
```

*Note since this is just an attribute value ends with selector if the class name appears in the end of the list of classes for an element and ends with `-delete-confirm` will be only considered*

Use ends-with selector and combination of your class selector.

For pure selection you can do this (Doesn't matter where it appears in the classList or how many classes it has):

```
var regExp = /-delete-confirm(\s|$)/; //I am sure regex can be improved

var $allofthem = $('a').filter(function(){
    return regExp.test(this.className) || $(this).is('.delete-confirm');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XS4dh/)**

Comment: PSL, thanks so much!!! That combination of class selector is new to me. Very neat.

Comment: @jcsanyi You are right just need one at the end to ensure it is terminated with that or space for the next one.

Answer (score 3):

### Is class just another attribute?

The problem with this type of situation is that treating class as just another attribute, and using attribute selectors will rarely get you what you're looking for in a consistent manner.

Some items to be aware of:

- Does it work if the item has multiple classes?
- Does it work if the item has multiple classes and the one you're matching against is the first class that shows up in the attribute value?
- What about if it's the last one?
- Does it work if the item has a class that contains the classname you're looking for? (in your example, maybe `no-delete-confirm-available`)?

Keep in mind too that when you're adding and removing classes dynamically, there's no guarantee which order the classes will show up in when you get the value of the `class` attribute.

If you have a very strict set of circumstances this will be used in and especially if the element will only have 1 class, an attribute selector may work. Otherwise, I'd recommend that you use a different approach.

### A different class

The proper way to handle this is to use a different class - maybe have whatever process is adding the `*-delete-confirm` classes also add another class - maybe `has-delete-confirm` or something. Then you can select on that, and not have to worry about the class attribute.

### Select all and then filter()

Another option that's not ideal, but will work better than an attribute selector is to select all possible elements, and then `filter()` your results with a callback function that uses a regular expression to find matching classes.

For example, if the elements are all `<a>` children of `#links`, you could use this:

```
$('#links a').filter(function () {
    return /(^|\s|-)delete-confirm(\s|$)/.test($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

---

> You may also find this this similar question to be of interest:
>   [jQuery:How to select elements with particular class here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229088/jqueryhow-to-select-elements-with-particular-class-here/17229129#17229129)

Comment: jcsanyi, thanks for your thoughts. Very helpful. I will strictly and consistently use "-delete-confirm" or "delete-confirm" for those links that need confirmation before deleting something. Thanks for mentioning of the filter approach!

Comment: @curious1 it sounds like that'll probably work for you. I wanted to make sure I got the warning in here too though so others that see this question don't try to use it in more general situations.