# jquery: click for every id-element starting with

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I tried to find all `id`s starting with the string "matchItem_" and define a click-event for each. onclick i want wo execute a script with a URL parameter and change the image in this id-element. Unfortunately my syntax isn't right, I also tried with `.each.function` but I didn't get it.

```
$('[id^="matchItem_"]').each {
    
    $(this).click(){
     //...execute my script.php?urlparam=xx....;
     $(this).find('img').attr('src','/admin/images/ok.png');
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Answer (score 30):

You don't need the `each`:

```
$('[id^="matchItem_"]').click(function() {
   // do something
   $(this).find('img').attr('src','/admin/images/ok.png');
});
```

Comment: Guess there are lot of items to match... :p

Answer (score 17):

Your syntax is invalid because you forgot the functions.

```
$('[id^="matchItem_"]').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(){
           //...execute my script.php?urlparam=xx....;
         $(this).find('img').attr('src','/admin/images/ok.png');
    });
});
```

Or if all you're doing is assigning the `.click()` handler, you can do it without the `.each()`.

```
$('[id^="matchItem_"]').click(function(){
       //...execute my script.php?urlparam=xx....;
     $(this).find('img').attr('src','/admin/images/ok.png');    
});
```

This is because most jQuery methods will automatically act on every element in the jQuery object.

(edited to add closing parenthesis in code)

Comment: @michbeck: You're welcome. By the way, it if all the elements are of the same tag type, like `<div>`, you'll get better performance if you include the tag in your selector. `$('div[id^="matchItem_"]')`