# Make individual jquery ajax calls with checkbox using different context

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a dynamic call to php script using jquery. I have multiple input checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" id="driver[0]" value="log.example.com">
<input type="checkbox" id="driver[1]" value="api.example1.com">
<input type="checkbox" id="driver[2]" value="mail.example.com">
```

Using jquery, this is what I am trying to do,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#driver[0]").click(function(event){
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                var domain = $(this).val();
                //alert(domain);
                  $("#stage").load('call.php', 'submit=submit&domain='+domain);
              }
            });
         });
```

So as you can see, the jquery requires a selector here `#driver[0]` , which in my case can be either one of them only. So does that mean that I have to write seperate function for each checkbox?

Here is how the data is getting updated into the page.

```
      <div id = "stage" style = "background-color:#eee;">
         STAGE
      </div>
```

Since all the domains are getting dynamically generated, I am thinking of a more adaptive way to deal with this, but I am having no luck.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery: click for every id-element starting with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985136/jquery-click-for-every-id-element-starting-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this with one function dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      var domain = $(this).val();
      //alert(domain);
      $("#stage").load('call.php', 'submit=submit&domain='+domain);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a selector that selects all `id`s which start with `driver[`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^='driver[']").click(function(event){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      var domain = $(this).val();
      //alert(domain);
      $("#stage").load('call.php', 'submit=submit&domain='+domain);
    }
  });
});
```

It would probably be more elegant to start from the container of the `<input>`s though, if possible, eg:

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="driver[0]" value="log.example.com">
  <input type="checkbox" id="driver[1]" value="api.example1.com">
  <input type="checkbox" id="driver[2]" value="mail.example.com">
</div>
```

and then

```
$('#container > input').click(...
```