# select HTML text element with regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html-parsing, text-extraction

I want to look for `&copy;` in an HTML document, and basically get the entity the copyright is attributed to.

The copyright line shows up a couple of different ways:

```
<p class="bg-copy">&copy; 2011  The New York Times Company</p>
```

or

```
<a href="http://www.nytimes.com/ref/membercenter/help/copyright.html">
&copy; 2011</a> 
<a href="http://www.nytco.com/">The New York Times Company</a>
```

or

```
<br>Published since 1996<br>Copyright &copy; CounterPunch<br>
All rights reserved.<br>
```

I want to ignore the dates and intervening tags and just get "The New York Times Company" or "Counterpunch".

I haven't been able to find much on using regex with JavaScript or JQuery, though I get the impression that it can lead to major headaches.  If there is a better approach to this, let me know.

Comment: Don't use regex, rather use the DOM tree to find what you are looking for. Some link : http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics

Comment: Normally the response you'd get is - please, don't use regex for JS parsing. Use JS parser. Question is - can you?

Comment: @ZenMaster Regex is **NOT** the tool for this kind of parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a robust solution, you will probably need a combination of DOM navigation and some heuristics. Your examples are solvable with regex, but there are so many more scenarios possible...

```
&copy;[\s\d]*(?:<\/.+?>[^>]*>)?([^<]*)
```

works for your three samples. But ONLY for them and similar cases.

See on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/fmdG2lmY8N)

Explanation:

```
&copy; // copyright symbol
[\s\d]* // followed by spaces or digits 
(?:</.+?>[^>]*>)? // maybe followed by a closing tag and another opening one
([^<]*) // than match anything up to the next tag
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/193787/518587) answer on how to use in javascript with jquery. Basically you can use the match(/regex/) function:

```
var result = string.match(/&copy;[\s\d]*(?:<\/.+?>[^>]*>)?([^<]*)/)
```

Comment: thanks, I see that that works, but I decided to find "&copy;" encoding in a page and parse that element.  However, now I'm having trouble with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282250/jquery-contains-returns-nothing-for-html-encoding

Comment: also, would you mind breaking down your regex for me? I don't really understand it. and how would I use this in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*:contains(©)').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('*:contains(©)').length == 0
}).text();
```

test it here http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/kGPYA/