# JQuery "contains" returns nothing for html encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encoding

```
var foundin = $('*:contains("the")').last();
```

works on a page, but

```
var foundin = $('*:contains("&copy")').last();
```

returns nothing, even though '&copy' does appear in the page source.  I tried escaping the '&', but that doesn't work either.  Is there a way to use contains to find an html encoded character in a page?

Basically, what I want to do is find the element contains © and parse it to get the copyright holder.  I asked a similar question aiming at this with regex here: [select HTML text element with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946922/select-html-text-element-with-regex/7947360#comment10198784_7947360)

Comment: replace & with &amp; that will match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty:

```
var $div = $("<div>");

$.expr[":"].containsEnc = function(a, b, c, d) {
    var decoded = $div.html(c[3]).text(); // decode &copy to ©

    return ~a.textContent.indexOf(decoded); // does the element contain the character
};
```

Then you can use `containsEnc` as a selector:

```
$('body:containsEnc("&copy")').html('ok');
```

It may not be the safest and most performant, though.

http://jsfiddle.net/wfLur/1/

Comment: Don't you think `... > -1` is clearer than `~...`? Just a thought.

Comment: @minitech: Probably, but since `~` is basically never used it has gotten the meaning "contains" for me...

Comment: well, that does work, but it doesn't really help me with what I'm trying to do, since it returns the longest div element containing &copy, I think?  I edited the original question, I'm basically trying to parse the copyright holder.

Comment: @tarayani: No, not at all in fact. The div is just a temporary tool to make the browser decode `&copy`. You can use the selector to select all elements containing `&copy` (or some other character(s)).

Comment: @tarayani: This is a fiddle which is more related to your scenario I guess: http://jsfiddle.net/wfLur/6/. You can use your original selector, but with `containsEnc` instead of `contains`.