# How do you select all id tags that contain a certain string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application that renders multiple questions with the option to provide an explanation for the answers given.

```
<label for="[<%:count %>].AnswerExplanation_<%: i+1 %>" id="[<%:count %>].toggleExplanation_<%: i+1 %>"><strong>Add Explanation</strong></label>
<br /><br />
<div id="[<%:count %>].Explanation_<%: i+1 %>">
    <textarea id="[<%:count %>].AnswerExplanation_<%: i+1 %>" name="[<%:count %>].AnswerExplanation_<%: i+1 %>" class="ckedit"></textarea>
</div>
```

so you will have id's like "[X].toggleExplanation_Y" corresponding to "[X].AnswerExplanation_Y"

I am writing a javascript function to show/hide the AnswerExplanation divs, and was looking for a way to select every id containing "toggleExplanation" I should be able to get the rest from there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery selector regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Comment: See the second answer on the above link

Comment: give them a class. It'll be better on many levels.

Comment: First off, you should realize that a CSS id must start with a letter A-Z and a-z and then may be followed by letters, digits, hyphen, underscore, colon and period.  Brackets are not legal characters in an id.  Periods and colons create challenges for CSS selectors as those are special characters in CSS selectors in jQuery or CSS files. Since you're generating the HTML, it's much easier to just put a common class on all questions.  You can then easily fetch them all in jQuery.  You can still have a unique identifier on each question that you can use to match it to an answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try using the [attribute contains collector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('label[id*="toggleExplanation"]')
```

Answer (score 21):

If your using jquery you can use this to select everything containing "toggleExplanation"

```
$("[id*='toggleExplanation']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Give all the `.toggleExplanation_` divs a unique marker CSS class. Then you can simply use jQuery to select all elements with that class.